# Saving session or process state in linux

Tags: c, linux, bash, unix, libc

I have to create a functionality for my project like saving session and further resume it from the same position in future. So I need to know how save the state of a process and then read from disk and resume it afterwards.

PS. The application is an interactive shell for a language and I need to extend it include a save session and resume session. But we want the code to be generic enough to be used in other places too.

Comment: ... and the question is?

Comment: @pfnuesel question is how do you save the state of the process to memory and then resume it afterwards reading it from memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a challenging task. The basic idea is to interrupt the process with a signal, at which point the OS puts the state of all registers (including the instruction pointer) in memory where you can access them if your shell has spawn the process you want to interrupt.

For more detail, you can look how checkpointing utilities handle that problem:

- [dmtcp](http://dmtcp.sourceforge.net/)
- [BLCR](http://crd.lbl.gov/groups-depts/ftg/projects/current-projects/BLCR)
- [Criu](http://criu.org/Main_Page)

Comment: Can you please explain it a bit more

Comment: No... I know the big picture but I do not know the details, hence the links to working implementations. I know enough to use them, not to explain in detail how they work. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

That is quite hard to answer in general other than “save the program's entire state to a file and load it from there on resume”. That can be very tricky because you might need to restore things like file handles and sockets, which may not even be possible if things have changed during the suspended state. But it may suffice for you to support something less than that and only save the information necessary to approximate the previous state (e.g., save the list of program files to load, or the save user's command history and replay it, etc).

Comment: Replay will be slow. Isn't some support provided by linux/unix for doing the same.